# on change function of jquery not working in Django form

Tags: jquery, django

I am building a django form like following:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Election Application |
    {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js">
  </script>       
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        });
        $('#id_state').on('change', function() {
            alert( this.value );
        });
    </script>
       </head>

     <body>

    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

     </body>
  </html>
```

In the above form, when the form is loading in browser, the on change function is not working. Can anyone please suggest what mistake I am doing here?

Comment: you need to move the on change listener inside the document.ready..

Comment: Any js error you got???

Comment: You are running js code `$('#id_state')` sooner than the creation of dom element `id_state`. Move script code after content block or move it inside `$(document).ready` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot @karthikr,  Mehran Torki

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it is better to use Pure Javascript to check if the document is loaded, and then, inside that ready function, use any jQuery you want. It is because jQuery is still not loaded completely and you want to add the listener with that.

This solution works for me:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  $('#id_state').on('change', function() {
            alert( this.value );
        });
});
```